# CSV sorting by field and view only selected rows

Tags: php, sorting, csv, documentation

I been trying to figure how first read a Google docs CSV (live) to be shown as a custom HTML.

The CSV have 50 lines and each line have 15 cells.

With a bit searching i figure out to this :

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Aus5xZRHSuhydGpmcXBRN0Z2WXM5Sks3TlgydF92R1E&single=true&gid=3&output=csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

print "<custom code>" . $line_of_text[0] . $line_of_text[1]. $line_of_text[2] . $line_of_text[3] . $line_of_text[4] . $line_of_text[5] . $line_of_text[6] . $line_of_text[7] . $line_of_text[8] . $line_of_text[9] .$line_of_text[10] . $line_of_text[11] . $line_of_text[12] . $line_of_text[13] . $line_of_text[14] . $line_of_text[15] . "<br>";
}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

But what i would need is to view only the row that have the value "(T01S)" in the first cell "A2" or first "$line_of_text[0]" and the header (first line).

I was thinking about just to show a "desired_line" would not help me as if i add a line in the middle many pages would show the wrong line.

Also is it any easy way to show one full line except the first cell? So i can have a custom code on that field? And also so i do not need every pages code if i add more fields?

After many hours of searching i would be very happy for any kind of help!

Comment: Please show an example input file, with it's corresponding desired output.

Comment: The easy one to do is the full price list : [link](http://www.the-pirate-way.com/products.html) But then i want only to show one products price "line" on each product page : [link](http://www.the-pirate-way.com/products/custom-men-styles/t1s-t-shirts-style-1-standard.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a easier way doing this using googles own API!

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,B,C,D,E,F,I,J+where+A=%27%28T01S%29%27&key=0Aus5xZRHSuhydGpmcXBRN0Z2WXM5Sks3TlgydF92R1E
```

This page lead me to the right direction : [OUseful.Info, the blog…](http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/)

And this is the google own page about this : [Google Docs Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

The google page have a good encoder to query the string on their page.

So by just using the link string i got exactly what i was looking for.